# Apache module dev: validate directory configuration

Tags: apache, apr, apache-modules

I am looking for a way to validate the relation of directives in every single directory configuration that is related to my Apache module. So lets say I have two directives which can be defined in a `<Location />` or `<Directory />` block:

```
AP_INIT_TAKE1("Directive1", set_directive1, NULL, OR_AUTHCFG, "Directive1"),
AP_INIT_TAKE1("Directive2", set_directive2, NULL, OR_AUTHCFG, "Directive 2"),
```

How and when can I make sure that both `Directive1` and `Directive2` were set and are not empty? There is no smooth way of getting all the directory configurations in an `ap_hook_post_config` hook. Checking the server config is pretty straightforward as it's accessible through `ap_get_module_config(s->module_config, &my_module)`, but what about directory configurations?

Right now I am maintaining a list of all directory configurations in the process conf pool (through `apr_pool_userdata_set`/`apr_pool_userdata_get`). This way I can retreive the dir configurations my module created within the `ap_hook_post_config` hook, but I can't imagine this is the way to go. It feels pretty hacky at least.

I would be very happy about ideas how to deal with this. I checked [`mod_example.c`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/examples/mod_example_hooks.c) as well as the [Apache API Doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__APACHE__CORE__CONFIG.html) but there doesn't seem to be a `ap_hook_post_dir_config` hook which fires, when the `<Directory />` configuration creation is completed.

**Update**: Sorry, forgot to mention I am developing in C

Comment: I have never seen a module do anything like that with directory configs.  When you consider htaccess and that each dirconf at runtime can be the result of many pairwise mergings it becomes hairy quick.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @covener! You are probably right, I do the directory config validation on each request now, which kind of makes sense when you think of allowing directives in htaccess, too. I still think there would be use cases for a post directory config hook (e.g. when the directive is only allowed in `*.conf` (not .htaccess) files (`ACCESS_CONF`); My specific use case is comparable to this: when the `ApiUser` directive is set, we need `ApiPassword` as well.